# CCSprite strange movement

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm writing a game using cocos2d-x and I have such problem:
When sprites are moving it seems like they are bouncing a little bit..

In game, objects are falling from top to bottom with some constant speed.
so this objects are added on a CCNode and I change only it's Y position like this:

```
 void GamePlayBase::updateParallax(float delta) {
        parallaxNode->setPositionY(parallaxNode->getPositionY() - GameRunningSpeed * delta);
    }
```

which is called from update function(scheduleUpdate());
Also fps is always 60 at every device, but deltaTime is between 0.002 to 0.009 on iPhone 4 or some android devices..
I did some optimizations and if object is not visible on the screen I deactivate it's physics body and hiding the whole object.

Edit:
I changed parallax update to have rounded positions:

```
  parallaxNode->setPosition(ccp(parallaxNode->getPositionX(),
                                  floor(parallaxNode->getPositionY() - GameRunningSpeed * delta + 0.5)));
```

and also fixed timestep:

```
void GamePlayBase::update(float dt)
{    
    static float ac = 0.0;
    static float c = 1./60;
    if (dt > c) {
        ac += dt - c;
        dt = c;
    }else {
        float t = c - dt;
        t = min(t, ac);
        ac -= t;
        dt += t;
    }

    updateGameObjects(dt);
}
```

it is almost fixed but still has a little jerky movement ..

Comment: Why don't you use CCActionIntervals to move the sprites ? It would be simpler and I bet it works smoothly.

Comment: you can't do that if you have acceleration, or stuff like that :)

Comment: Hi I use this in my projects for a long time and work well. For the first time, is little complicated but when you get the glue how it works you will like it. http://plaincode.blogspot.cz/2012/05/fixed-timestep-in-cocos2d-x-with-box2d.html original article about general problem is here http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/